# Do we need a property of Customer together with a property of CustomerId in Order model class?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I am very new to Entity Framework and data-based application.

Let the `Customer` data model class be as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //others properties have been omitted for the sake of simplicity.
}
```

And the `Order` data model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public Customer Customer {get;set;}
    // other properties have been omitted for the sake of simplicity.
}
```

My question is: "Do we need a property of `Customer` together with a property of `CustomerId` in `Order` model class?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't. The `Customer` object in `Order` class is sufficient to identify the customer ID. Further, you might want a collection of orders in `Customer` class, so that you know how many orders the customer has easily, something like this:-

```
public class Customer {
  private Long customerId;
  private String name;
  private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>();

  // ... getters/setters 
}

public class Order {
  private Long orderId;
  private Customer customer;

  // ... getters/setters
}
```

So, if you want to retrieve the customer ID from an order, you will do something like this:-

```
order.getCustomer().getCustomerId();
```

Comment: Considering the performance, which one is better: having a `Customer` property in `Order` class or having a `CustomerId` property  in `Order` class?

Comment: They are both equally about the same, the performance difference is negligible. Further, you want to group all customer related information in `Customer` class, and by having `customerId` property in `Order` class, then you lose the sense of data encapsulation. I mean, if you have `customerId` property in 2 places and one day the `customerId` value changes, then you will need to change the `customerId` value all over the places.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for your explanation.